# Constructing an algorithms decision tree

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, graph, tree

I was asked to do this question in an interview this evening :

Construct the decision tree for any three inputs into this algorithm:

```
For i = 1 to n - 1 do
    If L[i] > L[i+1] 
       swap(L[i],L[i+1])
For i = n-1 downto 2 do
    If L[i] < L[i-1] 
       swap(L[i],L[i-1])
```

I believe my solution to be incorrect as I came out with 16 leaves. I did the following :

```
                                    Root : 
                                  {a, b, c}
                                    /   \
                       (i>i+1)     /     \  (i<i+1)
                                  /       \
                              {b,a,c}        {a,b,c}
                               /   \          /   \
                              /     \        /     \
                             /       \      /       \
                       {b,c,a}   {b,a,c}   {a,c,b}   {a,b,c}
```

This finished the first loop, I then expanded the input to the second loop in the same way, at each node assuming that one decision went < and one went >, each time resulting in two answers from every node and eventually giving you 16 leaves.

Was this correct? If not, how should this be done?

Answer (score 1):

For `n = 3`, the second loop runs only once, for `i = 2`. So with two answers from each node, you get 2*4 = 8 leaves.